# Why I get this error everyime? `Missed schedule`

Tags: php, wordpress, centos7, schedule

I'm getting an error `Missed schedule` on WordPress. I get this error while I try to publish content or after I make a change something including updating some CSS(Customizer). I have never encountered such a problem before with WordPress. My server is completely under my control.

1. Checked in WordPress date and time
2. Checked server date and time
3. Checked PHP date and time zone.
4. Disabled all of the plugins and reactivated one by one still doesn't work.

I made research about that but most people are providing solutions with plugins. But I don't need to use kind of plugins.

- OS: CentOS 7 64bit + Plesk Onyx
- PHP Version: 7.4.8 run as FastCGI
- Wordpress Version: 5.5
- Theme: Generatepress

Answer (score 0):

[Somebody](https://es.wordpress.org/support/topic/error-al-publicar-cambios-en-apariencia-del-tema/) has fond a workaround: change CentOS+Plesk to Ubuntu+Plesk.

I have finally found a solution to the problem. Changing the system is not a useful option for me.

In this forum they explain the problem: [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371454/error-trying-to-publish-immediately-post-status-future-missed-schedule-error)

And it brings us an explanation in the plesk forums: [here](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/utc-time-issue-plesk-php-7-3-7-4-on-centos7.356169/)

It is basically a problem in CentOS7, the UTC file is not valid and this causes problems in publishing changes in WordPress.

The problem is solved by replacing that file "/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC" with a correct copy (I have taken it from another server with CentOS6).

And everything works correctly. You don't even need to reboot.

Comment: Can you identify that "Somebody"?

Comment: See last entry here: https://es.wordpress.org/support/topic/error-al-publicar-cambios-en-apariencia-del-tema/

Comment: Thanks. But please [edit] that into the answer. But do not turn it into a link-only. I.e. keep the summary you provided.